# Issue in 'View source' of artifactory 5.2 and 5.1 version

Tags: artifactory

I am facing issue in 'View Source ' option of the artifactory.

The **.drl** file I want to view is in a jar and I have added mimetypes for some extensions that I need.

```
<mimetype type="application/drools" extensions="drl, drt" viewable="true" syntax="java" />
```

What happens is that sometimes I am able to see the content of the file and sometimes it just shows an empty textarea and nothing else.

In 4.16.1 version there is no such issue.

Sometimes if I relaod the page or open in incognito then the description appears but if I reload again then there is nothing except the textarea. Means this is actually non predictable and generally it shows blank textarea instead of content.

I have faced similar issue in 5.1 versions as well.

Should I use 4.16.1 or there is something that i am missing in the configurations or settings or in mimetypes?

### Snapshot for 4.16.1 version

[image: Snapshot for 4.16.1 version]

### Snapshot for 5.2.1 version

[image: Snapshot for 5.2.1 version]

Comment: Is this the pro version or HA?

Comment: This is the OSS version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we've identified the bug you reported (thanks by the way) - it'll be included in our upcoming release 5.4.0 (around 2 weeks I think).

You can follow the issue [here](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14341)